# Ripple effect only working on open, not when opening

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for the confusing title.

So I have a ripple-effect javascript which works.  I have a form button with it but if the form isn't filled out, the ripple effect won't trigger.  But once it's filled out, it will.

How can I alter this code so even if the form isn't filled out, I can click the button to see the ripple effect.

```
(function($) {
  $(".ripple-effect").click(function(e) {
    var rippler = $(this);

    // create .ink element if it doesn't exist
    if (rippler.find(".ink").length == 0) {
      rippler.append("<span class='ink'></span>");
    }

    var ink = rippler.find(".ink");

    // prevent quick double clicks
    ink.removeClass("animate");

    // set .ink diametr
    if (!ink.height() && !ink.width()) {
      var d = Math.max(rippler.outerWidth(), rippler.outerHeight());
      ink.css({
        height: d,
        width: d
      });
    }

    // get click coordinates
    var x = e.pageX - rippler.offset().left - ink.width() / 2;
    var y = e.pageY - rippler.offset().top - ink.height() / 2;

    // set .ink position and add class .animate
    ink.css({
      top: y + 'px',
      left: x + 'px'
    }).addClass("animate");
  })
})(jQuery);
```

the ripple effect does work on disabled buttons and buttons that go no where but it seems to not work only when a form is invovled and the required fields aren't yet filled out.

Comment: The code itself doesn't seem to have anything that would act in the manner you are describing. It might have something to do with the 'submit' button's default functionality - as it analyses the form. Might be wrong, but these are my two cents on the matter, maybe it helps.

Comment: Hm, makes sense. I did find css that would fix this but it's not as "customized" as the jquery in the sense of targeting the click location.  css would, to my understanding, only work on the settings and not take click location into the code